# Am working on Android application. I want only my custom app shortcut should appear in launcher screen not the default icon

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, shortcut, launcher

Am working on Android project. I want to make only my custom shortcut should appear in launcher screen in Android. So that whenever the user tries to uninstall the app from the launcher. Only app shortcut should be deleted no app uninstall should take place at all.

In simple I just want user can't uninstall my application once installed but can access from shortcut from the launcher.

Any alternatives? Any suggestions? Sample code, please.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Please describe your research and show the result of your effort before posting a question.

Comment: I think you are talking about widgets. https://www.androidauthority.com/create-simple-android-widget-608975/